# how to implement a flexigrid in a dialogbox

Tags: codeigniter, flexigrid

I tried to implement a flexigrid in a dialog box.

Controller code:

```
 function grid(id){
    $colModel['s.no'] = array('S. No',50,TRUE,'center',0);
    $colModel['Name'] = array('Name',200,TRUE,'center',0);
    $gridParams['title'] = "Farmer List";   
    $grid_js = build_grid_js('flex1',$surl,$colModel,'id','desc',$gridParams);
    echo $grid_js;
 }
```

This is my code in my view.

```
 function view(id){
$.post("<?php echo site_url()?>controllerName/grid/"+id,{},function(data){
      $("#dialog_box").html(data);

    $("#dialog_box").dialog({
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        modal: true
    });
  });
 }
```

First i tried to populate the column name, but i didn't show up. When I print a number say "echo 10", this 10 is printed on the dialogbox.

I'm not sure what is the problem with my code and the same code works on a normal view(I mean other than dialogbox).

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.